# duplicate - miktex: \includegraphics[page=2]{file} always shows page 1

Tags: pdftex, miktex, pdfpages

I am facing the following problem since updating my miktex distro last time: The code below shows three times page 1 of file.pdf eventhough it should display page 1,2,3. Am I missing something? Known bug? Can someone reproduce that behavior?

```
\documentclass[
    10pt,
    a4paper
]{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\includepdf[page=1]{file}       % shows page 1
\includepdf[pages={2,3}]{file}  % shows two times page 1

\end{document}
```

**EDIT:**
Solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/375396/miktex-with-pdfpages-first-page-repeated-instead-of-actual-pages-of-original-p) mentioned by koleygr worked!

Comment: On my texlive on linux your code works as expected. Did you try to delete old aux file? (Just a thought)

Comment: On my Windows 10, with TeX Live 2017 distribution, and a `.pdf` with more than 3 pages, it works perfectly.

Comment: Check this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/375396/miktex-with-pdfpages-first-page-repeated-instead-of-actual-pages-of-original-p this is possibly a duplicate of this. If it solves your problem just inform as to mark it as a duplicate

Comment: I added miktex on your title since it seems to be miktex specific problem. Also someone have to change your `\includegraphics` to `\includepdf`

Comment: @koleygr Do you mean that the OP had `\includegraphics`? Then it ought not be changed to `\includepdf` by somebody else. But I think you mean the title doesn't match the OP's code.

Comment: @cfr ... Yes... I mean the title

Comment: @koleygr It isn't clear whether the `\includegraphics` should be `\includepdf` or the `\includepdf` should be `\includegraphics`. I guess the OP can tell us.

Comment: @cfr... the MWE is his original example... I think he just wrote the title like this by mistake

Comment: I meant `includegraphics`(but thats not that important because `\includepdf` is a wrapper for `\includegraphics`). The solution mentioned by koleygr worked! Thank you very much!