# includegraphics page option working incorrectly with lualatex

Tags: graphics, luatex

When compiling the following MWE (you need some random multipage pdf) with pdflatex, I get the expected result. When compiling it with lualatex, the includegraphics command includes page 1 of the pdf instead of page 2.
Is it a bug in graphicx V1.1a?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[page=2]{SomeMultiPagePDF.pdf}%
\end{document}
```

Log of lualatex, including output of \listfiles

```
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.0.4 (MiKTeX 2.9.6400)  (format=lualatex 2017.9.26)  5 OCT 2017 22:02
 system commands enabled.
**Testumgebung.tex
(./Testumgebung.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Lua module: luaotfload-main 2017/01/29 2.80001 OpenType layout system.
Lua module: lualibs 2017-02-01 2.5 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2017-02-01 2.5 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended co
llection.(using cache: C:/Users/JLo/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/luatex-cache/generi
c)
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is C:/Users/JLo/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.
9/luatex-cache/generic/names.
luaotfload | init : Loading fontloader “fontloader-2017-02-11.lua” from kpse
-resolved path “C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/luaotfload/fontlo
ader-2017-02-11.lua”.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@state = 1
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@noligature = 2
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@syllabe = 3
luaotfload | init : Context OpenType loader version “3.027”
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.define_font' at position 1 in `define_font'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload_color_attribute = 4
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is C:/Users/JLo/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.
9/luatex-cache/generic/names.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_
font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' at position 2 in `luaotfload.patch
_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.fixup_fontdata' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_fon
t_unsafe'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' at position 3 in `luaotfload.patch_font
'.
Inserting `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' at position 4 in `luaotfload.patch_font'
.
luaotfload | main : initialization completed in 0.804 seconds
Babel <3.13> and hyphenation patterns for 1 language(s) loaded.
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/base/article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/base/size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
luaotfload | db : Font names database loaded from C:/Users/JLo/AppData/Local/MiK
TeX/2.9/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.luc(load luc: C:/Users/JLo/A
ppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/lmroman10-regular.luc))
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
) ("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty"
Package: graphicx 2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty"
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
) ("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty"
Package: graphics 2017/06/25 v1.2c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty"
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
) (C:/Users/JLo/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/2.9/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: luatex.def on input line 99.
(C:/Users/JLo/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/2.9/tex/lualatex/luatex-def/luatex.def
File: luatex.def 2016/06/17 v0.01e Graphics/Color for luaTeX
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty"
Package: infwarerr 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
) ("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty"
Package: ltxcmds 2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
\Gread@gobject=\count87
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen103
\Gin@req@width=\dimen104
) (./Testumgebung.aux)
\openout1 = Testumgebung.aux

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 92.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 92.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 92.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 92.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 92.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 92.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 92.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 92.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 92.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 92.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 92.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 92.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 92.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 92.
(C:/Users/JLo/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/2.9/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count88
\scratchdimen=\dimen105
\scratchbox=\box26
\nofMPsegments=\count89
\nofMParguments=\count90
\everyMPshowfont=\toks15
\MPscratchCnt=\count91
\MPscratchDim=\dimen106
\MPnumerator=\count92
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count93
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks16
) ("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty"
Package: epstopdf-base 2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty"
Package: grfext 2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvdefinekeys.sty"
Package: kvdefinekeys 2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
)) ("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty"
Package: kvoptions 2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty"
Package: kvsetkeys 2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty"
Package: etexcmds 2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty"
Package: ifluatex 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX detected.
)))) ("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty"
Package: pdftexcmds 2017/03/19 v0.25 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)

("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty"
Package: ifpdf 2017/03/15 v3.2 Provides the ifpdf switch
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
\pdftexcmds@toks=\toks17
)
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 43
8.
Package grfext Info: Graphics extension search list:
(grfext)             [.png,.pdf,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PNG,.PDF,.JPG,.JPEG
,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps]
(grfext)             \AppendGraphicsExtensions on input line 456.
)
<SomeMultiPagePDF.pdf, id=1, 614.295pt x 794.97pt>
File: SomeMultiPagePDF.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use SomeMultiPagePDF.pdf>
Package luatex.def Info: SomeMultiPagePDF.pdf used on input line 93.
(luatex.def)             Requested size: 614.29349pt x 794.96806pt.

Overfull \hbox (284.29349pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 93--94
[][] 
 []

[1

{C:/Users/JLo/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
Overfull \vbox (244.96806pt too high) has occurred while \output is active []

[2<./SomeMultiPagePDF.pdf>] (./Testumgebung.aux)

 *File List*
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
graphicx.sty    2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2017/06/25 v1.2c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
  luatex.def    2016/06/17 v0.01e Graphics/Color for luaTeX
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2017/03/19 v0.25 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2017/03/15 v3.2 Provides the ifpdf switch
SomeMultiPagePDF.pdf    Graphic file (type pdf)
 ***********

)

Here is how much of LuaTeX's memory you used:
 1575 strings out of 494516
 100000,154059 words of node,token memory allocated
 353 words of node memory still in use:
   2 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 3 attribute, 45 glue_spec, 3 attribute_list
, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 2:25,3:2,4:1,5:22,6:2,7:13,8:3,9:12
 5596 multiletter control sequences out of 65536+200000
 15 fonts using 510519 bytes
 37i,4n,23p,263b,121s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
<c:/program files (x86)/miktex 2.9/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.ot
f>
Output written on Testumgebung.pdf (2 pages, 130086 bytes).

PDF statistics: 63 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 131072)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 100000000)
```

Comment: Update your miktex. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/375396/miktex-with-pdfpages-first-page-repeated-instead-of-actual-pages-of-original-p

Comment: I double-checked (Miktex package manager, listfiles, CTAN) to have the latest versions (lualatex 1.0.4, graphics 1.2c, graphicx 1.1a) and miktex shows no updates available in admin and user mode. I also synchronized package database in admin and user before that. I also reinstalled miktex-luatex-bin-2.9 and graphics package via admin package manager. Still, the problem persists. Any other ideas?

Comment: You have an quite old luatex.def (version 0.01e) here: C:/Users/JLo/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/2.9/tex/lualatex/luatex-def/luatex.def in your user tree. It hides the  current version 1.0f which is  in tex/latex/graphics-def/luatex.def. Try to deinstall it with the user package manager (perhaps package "luatex-def" or something like this).

Comment: Thanks! This was the solution. According to CTAN, luatex-def is distributed as part of graphics-def, so I installed graphics-def in admin mode and deleted it from the user tree manually (deleting with the package manager in user mode did not work). This solved the problem. If you post an answer, I will happily accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an quite old luatex.def (version 0.01e) in your user tree (`..../AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/2.9/tex/lualatex/luatex-‌​def/luatex.def`).

It hides the correct, current luatex.def (version 1.0f) which should be in  tex/latex/graphics-def/luatex.def.

Try to deinstall it with the user package manager (perhaps package "luatex-def" or something like this), or delete it manually.