# Texmaker with includepdf and pdfpages - how avoid superpositions of pages?

Tags: texmaker, pdfpages

I use texmaker and i have the following issue: i try to include un pdf file  www.pdf using includepdf. The compilation is fine but the output is wrong: it includes all pages of the pdf file www.pdf, but  repeats the first page of that pdf www.pdf as often as there are pages in the pdf file (superposition pages).
Can you help me?
Many thanks in advances
Best
Chiraz

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Is your system uptodate?  There was a bug with this behaviour some time ago https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/375396/miktex-with-pdfpages-first-page-repeated-instead-of-actual-pages-of-original-p